# How to exclude mailboxes within a smart mailbox?

Tags: mail.app, email

I have made some smart mailboxes in Mail.app. The smart mailboxes I am using only for my Gmail account.

While they send the emails to the smart mailbox they always send duplicates. The email from the Gmail account, email from the whole inbox and email labeled 'important'. Apparently every single email I get is labelled as 'important'. Whenever the mailboxes refresh, they add the duplicates back to the smart mailbox.

I only want one copy to appear in the mailbox. Is there a way to exclude these duplicates or am I just stuck with it?

Comment: Tell us more about your OS X version and your smart mailboxes, what are you doing with them?

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in Mail 4.5 (on Snow Leopard) it's easy: add a condition "Message is in Mailbox" to your smart mailbox's filter. In my case, that "Gmail" mailbox is a sub-box of the (unified) Inbox.

[image]

Comment: Is that a typo - don't you mean NOT in Mailbox - and then choose Important (and for Gmail you will need All Mail to be excluded as well

Comment: Yes, you could also use NOT IN to exclude all mailboxes but one. My solution instead only includes one mailbox.

Comment: Ah I have several mailboxes/tags on Gmail so your suggestion would not get me all the emails from gmail